# Functional test using Phpunit : InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit

I'm trying to test a form but i got unreachable field exception.

My controller's code :

```
class StudentController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @Route("/student/new",name="create_new_student")
   */
   public function newAction(Request $request){
      $student = new Student();
      $form = $this->createFormBuilder($student)->add('name',TextType::class)
          ->add('save',SubmitType::class,['label' => 'Create student'])->getForm();
      $form->handleRequest($request);
      if($form->isSubmitted()){
           $student = $form->getData();
           $name = $student->getName();
           echo "Your name is ".$name;
           die();       
      }

      return $this->render(':Student:new.html.twig',['form' => $form->createView()]);
   }
}
```

My StudentControllerTest :

```
class StudentControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

  public function testNew(){
    $client = static::createClient();
    $crawler = $client->request('POST','/student/new');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Create student')->form();
    $form['name'] = 'Student1';
    $crawler = $client->submit($form);
    $this->assertGreaterThan(0,$crawler->filter('html:contains("Your name is Student1")')->count());
  }
}
```

When i run the test using phpunit i got :

> InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field "name"

I'm following the tutorial from https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `$form['form_name[subject]']` syntax

```
public function testNew(){

      $client = static::createClient();

      //you should request it with GET method, it's more close to the reality
      $crawler = $client->request('GET','/student/new');

      $form = $crawler->selectButton('Create student')->form();

      $form['form_name[name]'] = 'Student1';

      // [...]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. Edit Test

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Create student')->form(['name' => 'Student1']);
```

Edit Controller:

```
...

$name = $student->getName();

return new Response("Your name is ". $name);
```

Do not kill what Symfony request.